# A.D.N. ou ADN ?

Tags: abréviations

Quelles sont les règles d'écriture des abréviations ?

Je ne sais pas comment je dois rédiger mon texte :

> Je fais des recherches sur l'ADN/l'A.D.N. pour mon projet de biologie.

Ça concerne l'acide *désoxyribonucléique*.

D'après [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acide_d%C3%A9soxyribonucl%C3%A9ique#:%7E:text=Les%20mol%C3%A9cules%20d%27ADN%20des,est%20un%20polym%C3%A8re%20appel%C3%A9%20polynucl%C3%A9otide.), on ne semble utiliser qu'ADN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pour un [acronyme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronymie), qui est formé des initiales de plusieurs mot (et quelquefois d'autres lettres) mais **se prononce comme un mot**, on ne met jamais de point. Les « vrais » acronymes qui ne sont composés que d'initiales sont en général toujours écris en majuscules, mais lorsqu'un acronyme est utilisé depuis longtemps et qu'on a tendance à oublier qu'il s'agit d'un acronyme, il peut s'écrire en minuscules (avec une majuscule initiale si c'est un nom propre). Pour les « faux » acronymes qui incluent des lettres autres que les premières du mot, les minuscules ont tendance à s'imposer. Par exemple:

> [OTAN](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organisation_du_trait%C3%A9_de_l%27Atlantique_nord) (prononcé [o.tɑ̃])

> [ENA](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_nationale_d%27administration_(France)) (prononcé [e.na] ; les acronymes omettent souvent les accents)

> [Insee](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institut_national_de_la_statistique_et_des_%C3%A9tudes_%C3%A9conomiques#Identit%C3%A9_visuelle_(logo)) (prononcé [in.se]), qui s'est longtemps écrit tout en majuscules (« INSEE ») mais dont le [logo](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institut_national_de_la_statistique_et_des_%C3%A9tudes_%C3%A9conomiques#Identit%C3%A9_visuelle_(logo)) est devenu « Insee » en 2013, ce qui a tendance à populariser la forme « Insee » dans le texte.

> [Medef](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouvement_des_entreprises_de_France) (prononcé [me.dɛf]), en principe pas capitalisé parce que ce n'est pas un « vrai » acronyme qui serait MDEDF ou MEF, est néanmoins [souvent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=MEDEF%2CMedef%2Cmedef&year_start=1995&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMEDEF%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMedef%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmedef%3B%2Cc0) écrit MEDEF.

> [sida](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syndrome_d%27immunod%C3%A9ficience_acquise) (devenu un nom commun : [« SIDA » est très vieilli](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?arcontent=SIDA%2CSida%2Csida&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSIDA%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSida%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csida%3B%2Cc0))

> [PACS, Pacs ou pacs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacte_civil_de_solidarit%C3%A9) (prononcé [paks] ; [la forme minuscule est apparue rapidement](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=PACS%2CPacs%2Cpacs&year_start=1995&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CPACS%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CPacs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpacs%3B%2Cc0), en même temps que le verbe *[pacser](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pacser)*)

Pour un [sigle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigle) qui n'est pas un acronyme, c'est-à-dire que l'on **prend les lettres initiales de mots et qu'on les prononce une par une**, on écrit le plus souvent en majuscules sans points. On peut mettre des points, mais c'est de moins en moins courant. En France, au moins, on a eu tendance à retirer les points des sigles vers la fin du 20<sup>e</sup> siècle.

> [SNCF](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9_nationale_des_chemins_de_fer_fran%C3%A7ais) (Société Nationale des Chemins de fer Français) (prononcé [ɛs.ɛn.se.ɛf]), s'écrivait [autrefois](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=SNCF%2CS.N.C.F.&year_start=1936&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3) S.N.C.F. La forme sans point est devenue plus courante dans les années 1970, et la forme avec points a presque disparu dans les années 1990.
> [SNCB](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9_nationale_des_chemins_de_fer_belges) (Société Nationale des Chemins de fer Belges), de même, [autrefois](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=SNCB%2CS.N.C.B.&year_start=1920&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSNCB%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CS.N.C.B.%3B%2Cc0) S.N.C.B. : il semble que la tendance à supprimer les points date à peu près de la même époque en Belgique et en France.
> [CFF](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemins_de_fer_f%C3%A9d%C3%A9raux_suisses) (Chemins de Fer Fédéraux [Suisses]), semble [courant depuis les années 1920](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=CFF%2CC.F.F.&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3), et C.F.F. de moins en moins courant dès les années 1950.

D'autres sigles français :

> [CGT](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conf%C3%A9d%C3%A9ration_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale_du_travail), de même, [autrefois](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=CGT%2CC.G.T.&year_start=1890&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CCGT%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CC.G.T.%3B%2Cc0) C.G.T.
> [PMU](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMU), de même, [autrefois](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=PMU%2CP.M.U.&year_start=1930&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CPMU%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CP.M.U.%3B%2Cc0) P.M.U.

> [ADN](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acide_d%C3%A9soxyribonucl%C3%A9ique) ne s'est [jamais couramment écrit avec des ponts](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ADN%2CA.D.N.&year_start=1860&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CADN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CA.D.N.%3B%2Cc0), soit par influence de l'anglais qui l'a inspiré, soit parce qu'il est n'est sorti de la littérature scientifique qu'à une époque où les points commençaient déjà à disparaître, soit parce que le N n'est pas l'initiale d'un mot séparé (**a**cide **d**ésoxyribo**n**ucléique). On n'écrit jamais <strike>Adn</strike> parce qu'on prononce les lettres séparément.

Pour une **abréviation qui n'est pas un sigle** (le plus souvent composée d'une ou plusieurs lettres **d'un seul mot**), on met un point à la fin sauf si la dernière lettre est incluse. Par exemple :

- « ex. » = *exemple*
- « M. » = ***m**onsieur*, « Mme » = ***m**ada**me***
- « c.-à-d. » = ***c**'est**-à-d**ire* (remarquer qu'on garde les traits d'union dans l'abréviation). L'abondance de ponctuation fait qu'il est fréquent de l'omettre complètement : « càd » est relativement courant, au moins dans des contextes informels.
- Un cas un peu particulier : [etc.](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/etc) prend en général un point, mais on peut aussi écrire « etc » sans point, parce qu'on a oublié qu'il s'agissait d'une abréviation (et de toute façon c'était une abréviation latine, pas française).

Answer (score 3):

En théorie, les sigles français prennent un point après chaque lettre. En pratique, plus ils deviennent connus et utilisés sans que la référence aux mots qui les composent reste présente à l'esprit, plus leurs points abréviatifs ont tendance à disparaître.

Une recherche de NGrams montre qu'A.D.N. n'a jamais été très populaire par rapport à ADN et est quasiment absent de nos jours. Si on compare avec SNCF, on voit une inversion de tendance vers 1980 et là aussi, une quasi disparition de la version "longue".

[image]

Je recommanderais donc d'utiliser la version la plus simple.

Answer (score 0):

Pour les acronymes normalement on n'utilise pas de point pour séparer les lettres, donc c'est bien ADN et non A.D.N.

Comment: "ADN" n'est pas un acronyme: un acronyme se prononce comme un mot et ne s'épèle pas lettre par lettre (par exemple, SIDA ou OTAN sont des acronymes).